# Providing example for worst case running time of a method

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

Could someone explain what the question exactly mean?

**Provide an example where the worst case running time for the contains( E val) operation in Binary search tree would occur.**

Method:

```
public boolean contains(E value)
{
    if (root.isEmpty()) 
        return false;
    BinaryTree<E> loc = locate(root, value);
    return value.equals(loc.value());
}
```

I went through the concept on when worst case occurs like

•   **Worst case** = slowest time to complete, with pessimal inputs chosen.
For example, the worst case for a sorting algorithm might be data that's sorted in reverse order (but it depends on the particular algorithm). But what does it mean by saying provide an example ???

Comment: smells like an Assignment.

Answer (score 0):

> Could someone explain what the question exactly mean?

You are required to come up with an example of an input where the running time of the code is maximal.

For instance, if you were running a search code on a list for item `x`, the worst case example would be a list where `x` is the last item in the list (if the code starts at the beginning and works forwards) or it would be the first item in the list if the code started at the end and worked backwards.

Answer (score 0):

I won't answer your homework for you, but I'll give you the following hints.

What's the worst possible legitimate (meets the definition) binary tree you can think of and sketch?  Given such a tree, what `val`s would make you have to go to the bottom of your evil tree to check whether your tree `contains(val)`?  What property do you notice about the sequence of values stored in such a tree, starting from the root and obeying the definition of a binary tree? How would such a tree come into existence?